# How to Store the session data(stream logs) of a EC2 ubuntu instance connected via putty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I wish to know how to implement session logging from a ssh session.

I want to collect the session data from the ec2 ubuntu session connected via putty.
All the commands that has been run in the session must me streamed and sent to cloudwatch logs or s3.

Any Suggestions??

I found that we can store the session data( stream logs) from session started from the Session Manager. But I want the same to be done from Putty session too.
Hope I get a solution.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use CloudWatch Agent to send the `history`command output to your desired CloudWatch log stream.

CloudWatch agent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

AmazonCloudWatch:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html